# Changes to Loopback App Not Being Deployed via slc deploy

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, process-management

I am attempting to deploy some changes to a loopback app running on a remote Ubuntu box on top of strong-pm.

The changes that I make locally are not being reflected in what gets deployed to the server.  Here are the commands I execute:

```
$slc build
$slc deploy http://IPADDRESS deploy
```

to which I get a successful deploy message which looks like this:

```
peter@peters-MacBook-Pro  ~/Desktop/projects/www/places-api   master  slc deploy http://PADDRESS deploy
Counting objects: 5740, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5207/5207), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5740/5740), 7.14 MiB | 2.80 MiB/s, done.
Total 5740 (delta 1555), reused 150 (delta 75)
To http://PADDRESS:8701/api/services/1/deploy/default
 * [new branch]      deploy -> deploy
Deployed `deploy` as `placesAPI` to `http://IPADDRESS:8701/`
```

Checking the deployed files on the server here :

```
/var/lib/strong-pm/svc/1/work
```

I can see that the changes I made to the local app are not reflected in what has just been deployed to the server.

In order to check that the changes are reflected in the build,  I checked out the deploy git repository, like so:

```
git checkout deploy
```

Inspecting the files here,  I can see that the changes I made are present.

**does anyone know why the changes are not reflected in what is deployed to the server ? **

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post but for anyone getting this issue I just encountered the same problem.

Finally I used slc arc and tried to Build from there.

Make sure that the "Fully qualified path to archive" has a correct value

It should be something like 
`../project-1.0.0.tgz`